# Different compile flags for same file in different targets

Tags: cmake

I would like to include a *.cpp-file* in two different targets (becoming two VS projects after running CMake). I would like to set different `COMPILE_FLAGS` for these projects.

However, when I do

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(myfile.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "flags1")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(project1 myfile.cpp)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(myfile.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "flags2")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(project2 myfile.cpp)
```

the `flags2` applies for both projects, so it seems like the properties are overwritten on line 3 and not considered on line 2. Is this true or am I missing something? Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 19):

Apply the `set_target_properties` command to the projects and not to the source files:

```
add_executable(project1 myfile.cpp)
set_target_properties(project1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "flags1")
add_executable(project2 myfile.cpp)
set_target_properties(project2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "flags2")
```

The flags set on the target will apply to all sources within the target.

Comment: thanks, but I am setting precompiled header options and they must be different for the precompiled.cpp and the other .cpps.

Answer (score 4):

If you adhere to a one target per subdirectory philosophy, you could do the following using `add_definitions` to add your compile flags.

---

```
# in ./CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(project1)
add_subdirectory(project2)
```

---

```
# in ./project1/CMakeLists.txt:
add_definitions("flags1")
add_executable(project1 ../myfile.cpp)
```

---

```
# in ./project2/CMakeLists.txt:
add_definitions("flags2")
add_executable(project2 ../myfile.cpp)
```

---

`add_definitions` applies to all files compiled in this subdirectory and those under it.  You can apply flags to specific files using the following:

```
set_source_files_properties(myfile.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "flags")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem as follows. In CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_target_properties (test1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "TARGET_ID=1")
set_target_properties (test2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "TARGET_ID=9")

set_source_files_properties (source1.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "FILE_ID=7")
set_source_files_properties (source2.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "FILE_ID=4")
```

In some header file:

```
  #if TARGET_ID==1 && FILE_ID==7
    #define SPECIAL_VALUE 17
  #elif TARGET_ID==1 && FILE_ID==4
    #define SPECIAL_VALUE 14
  #elif TARGET_ID==9 && FILE_ID==7
    #define SPECIAL_VALUE 97
  #elif TARGET_ID==9 && FILE_ID==4
    #define SPECIAL_VALUE 94
  #endif
```

Further, include above-mentioned header in both **source1.cpp** and **source2.cpp** and compile
I think, CMake has no more acceptable solution

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (how to specify per-target precompiled header dependencies on the same source file).  Luckily, the effect of set_source_files_properties is only the current directory (CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR). I was able to use that to come up with the following:

```
In source directory:

  CMakeLists.txt:
    add_subdirectory(lib_varient_1)
    add_subdirectory(lib_varient_2)

  LibSources.cmake:
    set(SOURCES
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Source1.cpp"
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Source2.cpp"
      ...)

    set_source_files_properties(${SOURCES} PROPERTIES
      COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yu\"stdafx.h\""
                    "/Fp\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stdafx.pch\"")

    set_source_files_properties(${SOURCES} PROPERTIES
      OBJECT_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stdafx.pch")

    set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/stdafx.cpp
      PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yc\"stdafx.h\""
                    "/Fp\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stdafx.pch\"")  

    set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/stdafx.cpp
      PROPERTIES OBJECT_OUTPUTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stdafx.pch")

    add_library(lib_varient_${VARIENT} ${SOURCES} stdafx.cpp)

In lib_varient_1

  CMakeLists.txt:
    set(VARIENT 1)
    include(../LibSources)

In lib_varient_2

  CMakeLists.txt:
    set(VARIENT 2)
    include(../LibSources)
```

This works because set_source_files_properties only has an effect on the current CMakeLists.txt file.  The included file will have different values for ${VARIENT} and ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} since it is included from two different CMakeLists.txt files.  You can also set various compilation flags, preprocessor definitions or include paths in each of the varient's CMakeLists.txt files prior to including the LibSources.cmake file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using 2 flags, one for the source-file, one for the target.

```
macro(enable_on_source target src)
    set_source_files_properties(${src}
                                PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-OptionModule")
    set_target_properties(${target}
                          PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-OptionTarget")
endmacro()
```

and during compilation I'm doing things only if both options are set.

This completely independent of directory-scopes and what not.