# How to recompile source file every time while using cmake 2.8.2 in single build for c++11 and c++98 for shared library creation?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, shared-libraries, c++98

I have a project directory structure of:

```
Root
  Source
    Common
      MyFolder
      ++ My 3 source files and header
```

When I am building my project it generates 3 to 4 shared libraries. **Lib1** compiled using c++98 and others using c++11. Flags are added in CmakeList.txt which is at root. 
I need my 3 source files to be compiled for **Lib1** and for other Libs as as well. but here what happens is compiler is first compiling my source file for lib using c++11 and then it is trying to use same .o file for Lib1 as well. So for .o file which is generated using c++11 is throwing exception when same is used for c++98 compiled library.

So how do write this in CmakeList.txt such that compiler rather than trying to use same .o file will compile source file again for Lib1(c++98 compiled library)

Is there any flag I can specify so that it won't take precompiled .o file and will compile it again ?

Here flags are not being overridden for different shared libraries but actually same object file by make file is being used for different flags

Comment: You need to show a minimal example of how you are building your two libraries and how they incorporate the same source file

Comment: The answer given by Calvin in form of make file is the exact thing I want, 
I just want to know how can we avoid using same .o file for same source file in cmake if we are using it in different shared libraries

Comment: I believe this is actually a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665887/different-compile-flags-for-same-file-in-different-targets). In any case, look at that (sakra's answer) and the only difference is you will use add_library instead of add_executable for the targets.

Comment: Your question is badly written and hence is unclear. I guess that you want to compile Lib1 twice, first time in C++98 and then in C++11 ? Then this question is a duplicate. Also please don't manually modify flags in CMake unless you really need - for your case you should use `set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11)` for example

Comment: No I want to compile different libraries with different flags. 
I have already set the target properties.
what happens is source is first compiled in c++11 and then .o reused while i am compiling same source for another library so what happens is std::__1 which is for std::string replacement of C++11 compiler is not recognised by c++98 compiler so it throws exception

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.  In my test, `add_library(lib1 test.cpp)` and `add_library(lib2 test.cpp)` recompile the source file, even with no flag differences, verified with a `#warning` directive in the source file.  Provide a minimal example and information on your toolchain.

Comment: okay which lib you built first ? whichever library you are building first build it with c++11 flag and then second library build it with c++98 flag.
you followed these steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of counter to how makefiles and `cmake` usually work.

Most users consider it really important that `make` performs an incremental build.

The usual way with makefiles is to do `make clean` which is supposed to remove any binaries and object files that were created.

However, sometimes I write cmake scripts that use globbing over the source directory to assemble the project. (That means, it says "just grab all `*.cpp` files in the `/src` folder and make an executable from them".) A makefile cannot check what files in a directory, so the make build will be broken after I add a new file, and `make clean` won't fix it -- the whole makefile will need to be regenerated by `cmake`.

Usually what I do is, I write a simple bash script, named `rebuild.sh` or something,

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j3
./tests
```

And I put that in the root of my repository, and add `/build` to my `.gitignore`. I call that when I want to do a full rebuild -- it nukes the build directory, so its foolproof. When I want an incremental rebuild, I just type `make` again in the `/build` directory.

The `rebuild.sh` script can also serve a double purpose if you use `travis-ci` for continuous integration.

Answer (score 0):

Most build system assume the compiled objects remain the same within the same pass. To avoid shooting your foot I would suggest telling the build system they were actually **different** objects, while still compiled from same source files.

I'm not familiar with cmake but this is how you do with make:

For example you have a a.cpp which you want to compile 2 times for different compiler options:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  printf ("Hello %d\n", TOKEN);
  return 0;
}
```

And the Makefile would looks like:

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_1 := $(patsubst %.cpp,%_1.o,$(SRC))
OBJ_2 := $(patsubst %.cpp,%_2.o,$(SRC))

all: pass1 pass2

pass1: $(OBJ_1)
        gcc -o $@ $(OBJ_1) -lstdc++

pass2: $(OBJ_2)
        gcc -o $@ $(OBJ_2) -lstdc++

%_1.o: %.cpp
        gcc -DTOKEN=1 -c $< -o $@
%_2.o: %.cpp
        gcc -DTOKEN=2 -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ_1) $(OBJ_2)
```

What I do here is generate two different list of object from the same source files, which you can even do the same for dependency(-MMD -MP flags).

Comment: This is what exactly I want , but I am not aware of Cmake Syntax that much yet just 2nd day at Cmake.
So if I want to be able to do same thing with cmake, how do I do that ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cmake. You may want to adjust your question since my answer(generate different obj), while it is what you intended, is not what exactly you asked(force recompile same obj).

Comment: The answer is only mildly related to the question. CMake works completely different.